# How to load layerd slider after scroll down in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am using Layer Slider in WordPress Version 3.8.
Now i want start slider after scroll down, i tried a lot to changes but no result.
Please reply if anyone found solution.
Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call your slider startup() function when scrolling Y position will reach at specific scroll value you want. By getting scroll value using

```
.scrollTop()
```

function of jquery.